# Is there a total binary computable function that specifies Turing machines with nonempty domain?

Tags: computability

I am working through Bridge's computablity book and I came across this problem that does not have an answer. I don't know how to precede, any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Give us a hint so that we'll be better able to help you: what do you understand about the background, what attempts have you made and why do you think they're problematic? We're a help site, not a question-answering site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Tip for you:
Check out [the second recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem#Kleene%27s_second_recursion_theorem) and plug $\Psi$ in for $Q$.

If you can't continue on you own here is my solution:

The second recursion theorem implies that there is such a $m$ that:
$$\varphi_m \simeq \lambda n.\Psi(m,n)$$

($\simeq$ means that the left and right expression are equal for every input $n$ equal and if an expression in undefined for a certain $n$ this is also true for the other expression)

Case 1: $\Psi(m,n) = 1$

This implies $f(m) = 0$ and thus $\text{domain}(\phi_m) = \emptyset$.
But notice that $\varphi_m \simeq 1$ is implied by our assumption.
Thus the domain of $\varphi_m$ is $\{1\}$. That's a contradiction.

Case 2: $\Psi(m,n) = \text{undefined}$

This implies $f(m) = 1$ and thus $\text{domain}(\phi_m)\neq\emptyset$.
But once again $\varphi_m \simeq \lambda n.\Psi(m,n) \Rightarrow \varphi_m \simeq \text{undefined} \Rightarrow \text{domain}(\phi_m) = \emptyset$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Nice, do you know any accessible and detailed proof of Kleene's second recursion theorem?

Comment: And I am curious, what if we allow f to be partial, would it still be impossible for f to exist?

Comment: The problem if a TM has an empty domain is the same as asking if it doesn't hold for any input. You could create a TM T that takes another TM X as input and simulates X on all possible strings. (you start X on the first string and let it make one step, you start X on the second string and make a step for the first one and one for the second string and so on...). If X domain contains at least one element the algorithm will find it in finite time; if the domain is empty however it won't halt thus the problem if "the domain contains at least one element" is "semi-computable".

Comment: I can't remember the proof actually;  I'll have to look it up

Comment: In the first case shouldn't it be $$ \Psi(m,n) = 1$$
? Does the proof still hold?

Comment: Ahh right thx. It still works because it only matters that $\Psi$ is defined or undefined.

Comment: How is  ≃0 is implied then?

Comment: Ooof I corrected it. sry. I forgot to change the other zeros to ones.